# How is the checked property of a radio button set in Angular?

Tags: angular, dom, radio-button, checked

In the following screenshot of the DOM, I have a radio input. The selected value is determined by an Angular `[(ngModel)]` property. You can see here the model property matches the value property for this input, so I assumed that's how it's determined as `checked`.

But while this exact HTML scenario happened to me before and Angular did seem to process it as checked, after a recent change I can't discern, now the `checked` property doesn't actually return as `true`. Once I start selecting values, everything does work as expected, but it's setting it initially that doesn't seem to register even though it's reflected in the HTML.

How is the `checked` property actually determined by Angular? Is setting the `ngModel` to the value not enough?

[image: Browser tool screenshot of DOM of Input/Label element]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a sidestep, but I ended up implementing the radio/model connection in the following manual way, by removing `[(ngModel)]` and using `checked` and `click` binding.

Formerly, `selectedAction` was the value assigned to the `[(ngModel])`, but now `actionIsSelected(action.id)` is doing an equality check with a pre-initialized `selectedAction` in the controller, and it's reassigned on click event.

`<input [id]="'action'+action.id" class="accessible" type="radio" required name="action" [value]="action.id" [checked]="actionIsSelected(action.id) ? 'true' : null" (click)="selectedAction = action.id">`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some quick scanning through the docs I found the [RadioControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor). Looks like Angular has a way built in.

I have also had luck using the following method for radio buttons and dropdowns. Although now I am tempted to try the `RadioControlValueAccessor` that is built in.

`<input #radioButton type="radio" (change)="processChanges(#radioButton.value)">`

This grabs the value on change and send it to the component for processing where you can update the Form Value.

Comment: Hmm, not sure the latter method will work for setting it initially, which is my main issue. It seems to detect changes fine.